# Symfony Custom User Provider

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm reading up on Symfony's way of managing users through the custom User Provider: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

> When a user submits a username and password, the authentication layer asks the configured user provider to return a user object for a given username. Symfony then checks whether the password of this user is correct and generates a security token

This works great when we're connecting to a database with user/password locally, but I want to authenticate against another service. Basically, I want to use Symfony as a client that consumes the user login service. This is how I would do it, except I don't have access to the password here.

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $uri]);
    $user_response = $client->get('api/v1/getTokens/', ['auth' => [$username, <passord>]);
    // $user_response 
}
```

And this is much different from what Symfony expects, which is to receive a user object and then issue it's own Tokens if the user/password match.

Should I forgo the whole Custom Provider interface for my own system?

Comment: The Symfony security component is arguably the most complex component out there.  Easy to go down the wrong path when starting out.  The UserProvider is for loading a user.  No connection to authentication.  So yes, forgo it.  What you probably want is a custom authenticator probably based on the guard authenticator. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: Try the KNP OAuth client bundle https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

Comment: @Cerad not only what you said above, but this was built one way, and now we're implementing completely differently and I have to figure out what we keep and what we trash.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [AuthenticationProvider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) to use in tandem with UserProvider you wrote.

Check also Guard [Authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html)